# How to interpret tensor form PDE in terms of matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations, tensors, matrix-equations

From this mathwork page "[c for system](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pde/ug/c.html#btlt6xj)", the usual second order PDE is written in tensor form:

$$ -\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{c} \otimes \nabla \mathbf{u})+\mathbf{a}\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{f}
$$

and $\mathbf{c}$ is claimed to be a $N$-by-$N$-by-$2$-by-$2$ tensor. Each side of the equation should correspond to a $N$-by-$1$ vector in this case, and now I am confused... I want to express this equation in matrix form, since $\mathbf{c}$ is a 4th rank tensor while $\nabla{u}$ is 2nd order tensor($2$-by-$N$ matrix?), how to define the tensor operation $\otimes$ then? Seems wiki doesn't give the answer.

Cand anybody elaborate the rule here? (Also how to cast the gradient operator in this case?) Any physical insight is honestly appreciated!

Comment: I'll translate this to abstract index notation because it will probably make the question clearer. The equation is $-\nabla^c c{}^a{}_b{}_{cd} \nabla^d u^b + a^a{}_b u^b = f^a$ (I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using abstract index notation:

There are two types of indices here: I will use $i,j,\ldots$ for indices relative to the domain (which appears to be $\mathbb{R}^2$) and $A,B,\ldots$ for indices relative to the co-domain (basically from the number of equations) which is $\mathbb{R}^N$. We can write $\mathbf{c}$ as the rank 4 tensor in index notation

$$ c^{A;ij}_{B} $$

(I included a semicolon just for clarity to separate the upper case and lower case indices.)
and adopting the Einstein summation convention your equation is

$$ - \nabla_i ( c^{A;ij}_{B} \nabla_j u^B) + a^A_B u^B = f^A $$

---

Without using indices:

Your tensor $\mathbf{c}$ can be thought of a $(N\times 2)\times (N\times 2)$ matrix, that is a square matrix with $N\times 2$ rows and columns. You can flatten $\nabla \mathbf{u}$ to an $N\times 2$ column vector. Then $\mathbf{c}$ acts on $\nabla \mathbf{u}$ by matrix multiplication.

The key, of course, is to flatten things the same way from $\mathbf{c}$ and $\mathbf{u}$.

Comment: Thanks! but I still can't be convinced $-\nabla\cdot(\mathbf{c} \otimes \nabla \mathbf{u})$ results in an N-by-1 vector. the stuff in the braket gives N-by-2 matrix, right? then what about the left divergence?

Comment: Yes, the stuff in the bracket is $N\times 2$, the 2 gets killed by the divergence. Think about the case where $N = 1$: the divergence of a vector (which is a 1-by-2 matrix) is a scalar (which is a 1-by-1 matrix). In the general case, the divergence act on each of the $N$ rows separately, collapsing each row (which is a 1-by-2 matrix) to a scalar. So you end up with N-by-1.

Comment: thanks! now I understand! in fact I don't know much about tensor analysis, do you know any reference that illutrates various tensor equations using matrix algebra?

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot help much with the book recommendations, but perhaps http://www.amazon.com/Vectors-Tensors-Equations-Mechanics-Mathematics/dp/0486661105/ref=pd_sim_b_8?ie=UTF8&refRID=1Y01JRXH4KYDZD3FK3M6 may work? For the type of equations you wrote down, you probably want to find a book on the mathematical foundations of elasticity though.

Comment: I go through the book.. some points are still obscure.. 1. the definition of $\otimes$ on wiki page is different(the dimension of the final product is increased while here reduce from Nx2-by Nx2 to Nx2), so the operation of $\otimes$ depends? 2. the divergence operator is usually represented by a row vector(here 1x2), so the stuff in the bracket should be 2xN rather than Nx2? 3. is there an explicit rule suggesting when to flatten a tensor during the calculation?

Comment: The use of the tensor product symbol $\otimes$ on the page you linked to is actually a pretty poor choice of notation. What you are working with is in fact tensor _contractions_ which sometimes is better denoted by $\cdot$ (to remind us the simplest case, which is the dot product). In fact, this is why a lot of people prefer to work with some version of the [abstract index notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation) since for products between higher rank tensors there are just too many possibilities to be concisely captured with a few binary operators.

Comment: There is no 'rule' about flattening tensors: it is up to the author to make clear which product between two tensors he is taking. In the webpage that you linked to, the author _did_ explain exactly what he meant (see the second displayed equation), even though his choice of original notation is poor. So the "flattening" rule you are looking for is exactly "what the author specified". // Regarding 2xN versus Nx2 : the ordering of rows versus columns does not matter in the grand scheme of things. What's important is making sure the indices line up correctly.